# IFrame into SalesForce

Tags: integration

I would like to surface SalesForce into our on prem SSO application via Iframes.

Currently we are hitting a snag whereby both VF pages and normal SFDC views do not support iframe rendering.

Is it possible to do this with SFDC?... Can I have an app with a chrome less view into SFDC cases surfaced in my portal in this way?

Answer (score 3):

You can. Sorta. *It's very quick and dirty and you probably shouldn't.*

1. create a View of your records, and get the Id: `fcf={view-id}`,
2. append the URL parameter which invokes console mode: `isdtp=lt`,
3. make sure the user has a valid Salesforce session (eg via SSO or user instructions!)
4. iframe thusly:
   `https://{instance}.salesforce.com/500?fcf=00Bb0000001SuIG&isdtp=lt`

[image: Console view]

**Tip:** the reason Salesforce / Visualforce pages mightn't appear initially is because the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY` HTTP header is served on the login page. It isn't enforced after login though (yet).

Comment: This looks... hacky. Can't even call it screenscraping, volatile-beyond-the-point-of-being-prone-to-breaking solution. Geez. You have my sword without trying it out, just for the fact a human being might be forced to go down this rabbit hole and actually pull out this sh*t with a "success".

Comment: Canvas s*xxx ;) At least for now. "I can put my app on Chatter page where it can't do any harm, wow". The APIs instead of iframes are there for a good reason :)

Comment: (Woops!) Agreed. Just because we can doesn't mean we should! Maybe better to iframe the on-premises application into Salesforce with Canvas ;-) LOL

Comment: Please don't shoot the messenger,  my preference would be API based.  But the architect has pushed this onto us.

Comment: If the login process prevents cross frames I don't see how this will work?... At some point I have to login and we passive browser login.  So therefore this gets worse as i will need a VF page that redirects me to my portal.  This doesn't sound elegant. :-(

Comment: What do you mean by "passive browser login"? Something like this? `https://login.salesforce.com/?un={your-username}&pw={your-password}&startURL=%2Fapex%2F{your-page}`
- yes it is inelegant, but you asked for frames! :P

Answer (score 1):

I've had to support a CTI solution which involved putting Salesforce into an iframe with the outer page also including a CTI toolbar.

It is fragile and its behaviour can be unpredictable features like the Service Console just don't work at all (Javascript errors).

If you want to 'surface cases' you might be better off using an API integration with SOAP or REST and building your own UI over the raw data feed from Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

A more recent approach that's now GA is Force.com Canvas, which provides an 'added-value' iframe integration with added security and simpler integration (either from JavaScript in browser, or from your server-side app).

This is a much better option than raw iframe approaches, and is supported by Salesforce.

For a longer answer on this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17484855/992887.